# Adding layout from one Class to another Class not working in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have two `Classes`, `Class A` and `Class B`, which can access each other.
 In `Class A` I have a `QVBoxLayout` called `mVLayout` and all the other layouts are going to be added to `mVLayout`. 
In `a.cpp`:

```
A::A(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    B testingB; //Class B object
    mWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(mWidget);
    mVLayout = new QVBoxLayout(mWidget);
    mVLayout->addLayout(testingB.mHLayout); //adding Class B mHLayout to Class A mVLayout;
    mWidget->setLayout(mVLayout);
}
```

and in `b.h`:

```
class A;

class B
{
public:
    B();
    QHBoxLayout *mHLayout;
    A *testingA; //Class A object
};
```

`b.cpp`:

```
B::B()
{
    QPushButton *btn1 = new QPushButton("Btn1");
    QPushButton *btn2 = new QPushButton("Btn2");
    mHLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mHLayout->addWidget(btn1);
    mHLayout->addWidget(btn2);
}
```

This works fine so far. But the reason why I made those two `Classes` can access each other is that I want to add `mHLayout` to `mVLayout` in `Class B`. Maybe the proper way to add layouts is the way mentioned above. But what if I do want to add layout to `Class A mVLayout` in `Class B`, is that doable? 
I tried this: in `Class B` constructor, by adding a new line (I also removed the addlayout line in `Class A` constructor):
`testingA->mVLayout->addLayout(mHLayout);` 

and I also tried this:

```
testingA = new A;
testingA->mVLayout->addLayout(mHLayout);
```

But it turned out I got this error:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   The process was ended forcefully.

Why would this happen? And can someone provide a way to add layout to `Class A` in `Class B`? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a matter of what has to be done first, what has to be done after ...

If you make B constructor like this (just an example, you can pass A's instance to B using a method):

```
B::B(A*a)
{
  QPushButton *btn1 = new QPushButton("Btn1");
  QPushButton *btn2 = new QPushButton("Btn2");
  mHLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
  mHLayout->addWidget(btn1);
  mHLayout->addWidget(btn2);
  a->mVLayout->addLayout(mHLayout); //here you add the layout
}
```

But in A's contructor:

```
A::A(QWidget *parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
{
  mWidget = new QWidget(this);
  setCentralWidget(mWidget);
  mVLayout = new QVBoxLayout(mWidget);
  mWidget->setLayout(mVLayout);

  B b(this);
}
```

you should call B constructor (and pass A's instance to it) after you set up A's widgets and layouts.

Obviously, you're not forced to create B instance in A constructor.
If you remove this line

```
B b(this);
```

you can do

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  A a(0);
  B b(&a);
  a.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

which works as well.